# How to solve this two problems in react.js - TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null and 'keyCode' is deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, types

I have two bugs in the code and I can't fix them. I use react.js I tried all possible solutions and in the end nothing. If anyone knows, let them help because I have reached a dead end.
This is the part of my code that should work according to the principle, when you click on the button it displays a drop down menu and when click again then close it.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Style.css";
import logo from "./Image/Logo/glavni-logo.png";
import "./Components/mega";
import image from "./Image/Mega/FAQ Logo.png";

 function Mega() {
  return (
  <div className="mega"> 
    <div className="mega-backdrop"></div>
    <div className="mega-inner">
      <div className="mega-header">
        <a className="mega-logo" href="/">
          <img src={logo} alt="SunControl" />
        </a>
  
        <a href className="mega-close siteheader-toggle is-active is-toggled">
          <div className="siteheader-toggle-buns">
            <span className="siteheader-toggle-bun"></span>
            <span className="siteheader-toggle-bun"></span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
export default Mega
```

Everything works on the page until a refresh is done and then reports bugs!

```
import $ from 'jquery'

(function() {
  var isClosing = false

   setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('js')
     }, 500)
    $(document).on('click', '.siteheader-nav-item.is-products, .siteheader-toggle', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation()
      var mega = $('.mega')
       if (mega.hasClass('is-active')) {
        close(mega)
        $(this).removeClass('is-active')
       } else {
          open(mega)
          $(this).addClass('is-active')
         }
       })

     document.querySelector('.mega-backdrop').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var mega = $('.mega')
         close(mega)
         })
```

First error is: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null in this line :

```
document.querySelector('.mega-backdrop').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var mega = $('.mega')
         close(mega)
         })
```

and in this line is second error :

```
$(document).on('keydown.mega', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    close(mega)
  }
})
```

in my code line with: if (e.keyCode === 27) is - 'keyCode' is deprecated. and it should not be crossed out.

I don't know if I asked the question well. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title for your question. Read [ask].

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing DOM manipulation to add a handler instead of doing it in react?

Comment: Also, **where** is the code `document.querySelector('.mega-backdrop').addEventListener`? Those are the likely problems.

Comment: The `Mega` function is not returning anything; it is also syntactically wrong (it's missing some closing brackets). Also where is it used? Please improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers.